# Calling forward function without .forward()

Tags: python, pytorch

While looking at some pytorch code on pose estimation [AlphaPose](https://github.com/MVIG-SJTU/AlphaPose/tree/pytorch) I noticed some unfamiliar syntax:

Basically, we define a `Darknet` class which inherits `nn.Module` properties like so: `class Darknet(nn.Module)`

This re-constructs the neural net from some config file and also defines functions to load pre-trained weights and a forward pass

Now, forward pass takes the following parameters:

```
def forward(self, x, CUDA)
```

I should note that in class definition forward is the only method that has a CUDA attribute (this will become important later on)

In the forward pass we get the predictions:

```
for i in range(number_of_modules):
     x = self.module[i](x)
```

where `module[i]` was constructed as:

```
module = nn.Sequential()
conv = nn.Conv2d(prev_fileters, filters, kernel_size, stride, pad, bias=bias)
module.add_module("conv_{0}".format(index), conv)
```

We then call invoke this model and (I presume) a forward method like so:

```
self.det_model = Darknet("yolo/cfg/yolov3-spp.cfg")
self.det_model.load_weights('models/yolo/yolov3-spp.weights')
self.det_model.cpu()
self.det_model.eval()

image = image.cpu()
prediction = self.det_model(img, CUDA = False)
```

I assume that the last line is the calling of the forward pass but why not use the `.forward`? Is this a pytorch specific syntax or am I missing some basic python principles?

Answer (score 18):

This is nothing torch specific. When you call something as `class_object(fn params)` it invokes the `__call__` method of that class.

If you dig the code of torch, specifically `nn.Module` you will see that `__call__` internally invokes forward but taking care of hooks and states that pytorch allows. So when you are calling `self.det_model(img, cuda)` you are still calling forward.

See the code for nn.module [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module).

Comment: While I agree with your explanation I would like to highlight that it is torch specific decision to make use of the python language feature. They could have achieve the same goal with a method call.