# Why there are different output between model.forward(input) and model(input)

Tags: model, pytorch, forward

I'm using pytorch to build a simple model like VGG16,and I have overloaded the function `forward` in my model.

I found everyone tends to use `model(input)` to get the output rather than `model.forward(input)`, and I am interested in the difference between them. I try to input the same data, but the result is different. I'm confused.

I have output the layer_weight before I input data, the weight not be changed, and I know when we using `model(input)` it using `__call__` function, and this function will call `model.forward`.

```
   vgg = VGG()
   vgg.double()
   for layer in vgg.modules():
      if isinstance(layer,torch.nn.Linear):
         print(layer.weight)
   print("   use model.forward(input)     ")
   result = vgg.forward(array)

   for layer in vgg.modules():
     if isinstance(layer,torch.nn.Linear):
       print(layer.weight) 
   print("   use model(input)     ")
   result_2 = vgg(array)
   print(result)
   print(result_2)
```

output:

```
    Variable containing:1.00000e-02 *
    -0.2931  0.6716 -0.3497 -2.0217 -0.0764  1.2162  1.4983 -1.2881
    [torch.DoubleTensor of size 1x8]

    Variable containing:
    1.00000e-02 *
    0.5302  0.4494 -0.6866 -2.1657 -0.9504  1.0211  0.8308 -1.1665
    [torch.DoubleTensor of size 1x8]
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`model.forward` just calls the forward operations as you mention but `__call__` does a little extra.

If you dig into the [code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module) of `nn.Module` class you will see `__call__` ultimately calls forward but internally handles the forward or backward hooks and manages some states that pytorch allows. When calling a simple model like just an MLP, it may not be really needed but more complex model like spectral normalization layers have hooks and therefore you should use `model(.)` signature as much as possible unless you explicitly just want to call `model.forward`

Also see [Calling forward function without .forward()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54989230/calling-forward-function-without-forward/54989851#54989851)

In this case, however, the difference may be due to some dropout layer, you should call `vgg.eval()` to make sure all the stochasticity in network is turned off before comparing the outputs.