# When do you want to explicitly call model.forward(input) in PyTorch?

Tags: python, class, oop, pytorch

In most PyTorch examples, I see `out = model(input)` instead of `out = model.forward(input)`. I understand that the latter doesn't handle any hooks, and the first option is [generally preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55343850/5194677).

However, in the Annotated Transformer [implementation of the Attention Is All You Need Transformer](https://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/2018/04/03/attention.html), they use `model.forward()` when getting the output from the entire model, but all layers within the model are called using `layer(x)` instead of `layer.forward(x)`. I assume this explicit use of `.forward()` is intentional, but can't figure out why.

Edit:
Very sorry for not being clear on what I meant by layer. The code I am referring to has structure like:

```
class model(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, layer1, layer2, layer3):
        super(model, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = layer1
        self.layer2 = layer2 
        self.layer3 = layer3

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layer2(self.layer1(x))

class layer1(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, inputs):
        super(layer3, self).__init__()
        ## set stuff here

    def forward(self, x):
        ## do stuff to x
        return x

class layer2(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, layer, N):
        super(layer2, self).__init__()
        ## set stuff here

    def forward(self, x):
        ## do more stuff to x
        return x
```

As you can see, within `model`, x is propagated through all the layers by just `layer(x)`, but in this particular example, the outputs are calculated by `out = model.forward(input)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you define your model, you have something that probably looks like this:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        
        self.layer_1 = nn.Linear(10, 64)
        self.layer_2 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
        self.layer_out = nn.Linear(64, 1)
        
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p = 0.1)
        self.batchnorm1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(64)
        self.batchnorm2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(64)
        
    def forward(self, inputs):
        x = self.relu(self.layer_1(inputs))
        x = self.batchnorm1(x)
        x = self.relu(self.layer_2(x))
        x = self.batchnorm2(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.layer_out(x)
        
        return (x)
```

forward() is a method of your model object, not your layer object. A layer object can take input as an argument, but you cannot call forward() on a layer because there is no forward method for these objects.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: So sorry, I realized I wasn't clear by what I meant by layer., and have edited the question.

Comment: In the example I was referring to, each layer actually inherits from nn.Module, and actually does have a forward() method.

Comment: @TheHagen No worries at all! That is interesting indeed. To my understanding you can do either call method (as you said) and one method simply discards hooks. Since layers are inheriting from the defined model, I would imagine it is the same for the layers as well. Since this code is coming from an academic paper, I'm thinking that they are using .forward() as a way to show exactly when the model is being trained. There is some info here as well: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/any-different-between-model-input-and-model-forward-input/3690

Comment: That could be it. I didn't find any hooks in their code, so maybe it is just a readability issue.