# Calling Class Function Without Period

Tags: function, class

New to python and it seems like a simple question but I haven't been able to find an answer. I found this code on [github](https://github.com/makeesyai/makeesy-deep-learning/blob/main/pytorch_nn/nn_basics.py). I can't understand why it doesn't say `model.forward(x)`.

```
import torch
from torch import nn


class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()

    def forward(self, x):
        tensor = self.flatten(x)
        return tensor


x = torch.rand(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
print(x)
model = NeuralNet()
output = model(x)
print(output)
```

Comment: "I can't understand why it doesn't say model.forward(x)" - It doesn't say many other things as well, so what kinda question is that???

Answer (score 0):

Refere to this [Why there are different output between model.forward(input) and model(input)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55338756/why-there-are-different-output-between-model-forwardinput-and-modelinput) and also read about

```
 __call__
```

method.