# can anyone explain what "out = self(images)" do in below code

Tags: python, oop, pytorch, self

I am not able to understand, if prediction is calculated in forward method, then why there is need "out = self(images)" and what it will do. I am bit confuse about this code.

```
class MnistModel(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.linear = nn.Linear(input_size, num_classes)
    
def forward(self, xb):
    xb = xb.reshape(-1, 784)
    out = self.linear(xb)
    return out

def training_step(self, batch):
    images, labels = batch 
    out = self(images)                  # Generate predictions
    loss = F.cross_entropy(out, labels) # Calculate loss
    return loss

def validation_step(self, batch):
    images, labels = batch 
    out = self(images)                    # Generate predictions
    loss = F.cross_entropy(out, labels)   # Calculate loss
    acc = accuracy(out, labels)           # Calculate accuracy
    return {'val_loss': loss, 'val_acc': acc}
    
def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
    batch_losses = [x['val_loss'] for x in outputs]
    epoch_loss = torch.stack(batch_losses).mean()   # Combine losses
    batch_accs = [x['val_acc'] for x in outputs]
    epoch_acc = torch.stack(batch_accs).mean()      # Combine accuracies
    return {'val_loss': epoch_loss.item(), 'val_acc': epoch_acc.item()}

def epoch_end(self, epoch, result):
    print("Epoch [{}], val_loss: {:.4f}, val_acc: {:.4f}".format(epoch, result['val_loss'], result['val_acc']))
```

model = MnistModel()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling forward function without .forward()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54989230/calling-forward-function-without-forward)

Comment: It calls the object, invoking the  `__call__` method

Comment: It calls nn.Module.__call__() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, `self` refers to the instance that you have created from a class (similar to `this` in Java and C++). An instance is **callable**, which means it may be called like a function itself, if method `__call__` have been overridden.

Example:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __call__(self, x, y):
        return x + y

a = A()
print(a(3,4)) # Prints 7
```

In your case, `__call__` method is **implemented in super class `nn.Module`**.
As it is a neural network module it needs an input placeholder. ***"out"*** is the placeholder for the data that is going to be forward the output of the module to the next layer or module of your model.

In the case of `nn.Module` class instances (and those that inherit from the class) the forward method is what is used as the `__call__` method. At least where it is defined with respect to the `nn.Module` class.