# What is self referring to in this PyTorch derived nn.Module class method?

Tags: python, class, pytorch

I am following this [tutorial](https://jovian.ai/aakashns/03-logistic-regression) for Pytorch and there is a line of code that makes no sense to me in the derived class `MnistModule` method `training_step` of the `nn.Module` class.

The line is
`out = self(images)`

Please can someone explain to me what is happening here? Is this correct or not and if this is convention to follow.

Thanks

Here's the snippet

```
class MnistModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(input_size, num_classes)
        
    def forward(self, xb):
        xb = xb.reshape(-1, 784)
        out = self.linear(xb)
        return out
    
    def training_step(self, batch):
        images, labels = batch 
        out = self(images)                  # Generate predictions
        loss = F.cross_entropy(out, labels) # Calculate loss
        print(type(out))
        return loss
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54989851/3236925 

This may be related to your query.

Comment: thanks I understood it

Answer (score 3):

It refers to an instance of `MnistModel`, the same as in any other method defined by the class. The only thing odd is that `self` is *called*, but that's explained by the fact that `nn.Module` defines `__call__`, so all instances of `MnistModel` are themselves callable.

`out = self(images)` is equivalent to `out = self.__call__(images)`.